# Proving (directly) the closedness of the closed ball $B_1(0)$ in a finite dimensional normed space.

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

**Context.** Let $X = (X,\|\cdot\|)$ be a finite dimensional normed space. I am trying to show that the unitary closed ball of $X$ ($B_1(0)$) is, indeed, closed with a direct proof.

**Attempt.** By definition,
$$ B_1(0) = \{x \in X \colon \|x\| \leqslant 1\}. $$
We say $B_1(0)$ is closed if it contains all of its limits points, i.e., if $\overline{B_1(0)} \subset B_1(0)$. Thus, let $x \in \overline{B_1(0)}$ be an arbitrary element. Then, there exists a convergent sequence $(x_k)_{k \in \Bbb N}$ such that $x_k$ converges to $x$. By definition of convergent sequence,
$$ \forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N = N(\epsilon) \colon \forall n \in \Bbb N, n > N \Rightarrow \| x_n-x\| < \epsilon. $$
Now, we just see that
$$ \|x\| = \|(x-x_n)+x_n \| = \|x_n - (x_n-x) \| \geqslant |\,\|x_n\| - \|x_n-x\|\,| \geqslant | \, \|x_n\| - \epsilon \, |$$
But I don't know how to proceed from here... Is this aproach correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do is to use the triangle inequality to get
$$
\|x\|\leq\|x-x_k\|+\|x_k\|\leq\|x-x_k\|+1<1+\epsilon. 
$$
As this can be done for any $\epsilon>0$ (by choosing $k$ big enough), $\|x\|\leq1$.

A second argument is to notice that $|\,\|x\|-\|y\|\,|\leq\|x-y\|$ implies that the function $\gamma:x\longmapsto\|x\|$ is continuous. Hence $B_1(0)=\gamma^{-1}([0,1])$ is a continuous preimage of a closed set, hence closed.

Comment: Kind of dumb from me to go and search for the reverse triangle inequality... Thanks for you simple (and good) answer! I don't understand one thing: Why is $\| x - x_k \| < \epsilon?$ From definition we have $\| x_k - x \| < \epsilon$. Is this same? If so, why?

Comment: It's a basic properties of norms, that $\|x\|=\|-x\|$ (more generally, $\|x\|=\|\lambda x\|$ for all $|\lambda|=1$. It has to be like that if you want the norm of the difference to give you a distnace. If you didn't have $\|x-y\|=\|y-x\|$, then the norm would not give you a distance and you would not be able to even be talking about "open", or "closed", or "closure".

Comment: Thanks for your help, it's clear to me now!